# Shapeless: extract case case field value parameterized by annotation

Tags: scala, shapeless

I am trying to generate a typeclass for returning the value of a case class field that has a particular annotation at compile time, using shapeless.

That's given a Scala annotation case class and a generic case class the typeclass `Identity[T]`
should return the value of the 'single' attribute annotated with such an annotation.

```
trait Identity[T] {
  def apply(t: T): Long
}

final case class Id() extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
case class User(@Id id: Long, account_id: Int, name: String, updated_at: java.time.Instant)
```

and given an instance of the case class and typeclass

```
val identity   = Identity[User] // implicit summoner

val user = User(1009, 101, "Alessandro", Instant.now())
val value = identity(user)
```

I'd like `value` to return `1009`

I tried to play around the following snippet, but I did get as far as to compute the `Symbol` name of the annotated field.

```
object WithShapeless {

  import MyAnnotations.Id
  import shapeless._
  import shapeless.ops.hlist
  import shapeless.ops.record.Keys
  import shapeless.record._

  // select the field symbol with the desired annotation, if exists
  object Mapper extends Poly1 {
    implicit def some[K <: Symbol]: Case.Aux[(K, Some[Id]), Option[K]] = at[(K, Some[Id])] {
      case (k, _) => Some(k)
    }
    implicit def none[K <: Symbol]: Case.Aux[(K, None.type), Option[K]] = at[(K, None.type)] {
      case (k, _) => Option.empty[K]
    }
  }

  implicit def gen[A, HL <: HList, AL <: HList, KL <: HList, ZL <: HList, ML <: HList](
    implicit
    generic: LabelledGeneric.Aux[A, HL],
    annots: Annotations.Aux[Id, A, AL],
    keys: Keys.Aux[HL, KL],
    zip: hlist.Zip.Aux[KL :: AL :: HNil, ZL],
    mapper: hlist.Mapper.Aux[Mapper.type, ZL, ML],
    ev0: hlist.ToList[ML, Option[Symbol]]
  ): Identity[A] = new Identity[A] {

    val zipped: ZL          = zip(keys() :: annots() :: HNil)
    val annotatedFields: ML = mapper.apply(zipped)

    val symbol: Symbol = annotatedFields.to[List].find(_.isDefined).get match {
      case Some(symbol) => symbol
      case _            => throw new Exception(s"Class  has no attribute marked with @IdAnnot")
    }

    println(s"""
               |zipped: ${zipped}
               |mapped: ${annotatedFields}
               |symbol: $symbol
               |""".stripMargin)

    override def apply(a: A): Long = {
      val repr = generic.to(a)
      val value = repr.get(Witness(symbol)) // compilation fails here

      println(s"""
                 |Generic ${generic.to(a)}
                 |value: $value
      """.stripMargin)
      1
    }
  }
}
```

I try to conjure a `Selector` to return the value but the compiler fails with `No field this.symbol.type in record HL`.

I cannot get it to work!
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need `LabelledGeneric` because you don't use keys. Try

```
import java.time.Instant
import shapeless.ops.hlist.{CollectFirst, Zip}
import shapeless.{::, Annotations, Generic, HList, HNil, Poly1}

trait Identity[T] {
  type Out
  def apply(t: T): Out
}
object Identity {
  type Aux[T, Out0] = Identity[T] { type Out = Out0 }
  def instance[T, Out0](f: T => Out0): Aux[T, Out0] = new Identity[T] {
    type Out = Out0
    override def apply(t: T): Out = f(t)
  }

  def apply[T](implicit identity: Identity[T]): Aux[T, identity.Out] = identity

  implicit def mkIdentity[T, HL <: HList, AL <: HList, ZL <: HList](implicit
    generic: Generic.Aux[T, HL],
    annotations: Annotations.Aux[Id, T, AL],
    zip: Zip.Aux[HL :: AL :: HNil, ZL],
    collectFirst: CollectFirst[ZL, Mapper.type],
  ): Aux[T, collectFirst.Out] = 
    instance(t => collectFirst(zip(generic.to(t) :: annotations() :: HNil)))
}

object Mapper extends Poly1 {
  implicit def cse[A]: Case.Aux[(A, Some[Id]), A] = at(_._1)
}

final case class Id() extends scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
case class User(@Id id: Long, account_id: Int, name: String, updated_at: java.time.Instant)

val identity = Identity[User]

val user = User(1009, 101, "Alessandro", Instant.now())
val value = identity(user) //  1009
```

Comment: Your solution calls **all** the shapeless methods in the `apply`  implementation. In my (partial) attempt I tried to factor as much as possible (that;'s why I used `keys`), the not run-time relevant code outside the `apply` method with a goal of having a light-weight  `apply` method that I can run on a large collection on data (ie. List of millions items). Would it possible to adapt your solution so that in the Identity `apply` method we **just** extract the value and keep the Shapeless boiler-plait code to live in the trait and not in the method  itself? Thanks

Comment: @GrayMouser Not sure I understand your question. You can refactor the code any way you want. You just don't need `LabelledGeneric`. `Generic` is enough.

Comment: what I meant is that your code executes the `collectFirst(zip(generic.to(t) :: annotations() :: HNil))` at **every ** method `apply` invocation. Those operations are quite heavy weight (a performance test on a collection of 1M `users` took more than 5secs, while an implementation based on manually creating the typeclass about 150ms. Is it possible to refactor your code into ?

```: Aux[...] = new Identity[T] {
    ...
    val extractor = //  here all heavy weight code 
     def apply(t: T): Out = extractor(..) // use  object above to extract the value 
  }
}
```
Thanks